# Error when connecting to postgres through renamed 'local host'

Tags: python, postgresql, server

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
connection = psycopg2.connect(
database = 'library',
user = 'postgres',
password = '1234',
host = 'grabel.ddns.net',
port = '5432')


(postgres-challenge-workspace) C:\Users\gabri\postgres-challenge-workspace>python library.py
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gabri\postgres-challenge-workspace\library.py", line 40, in 
connection = psycopg2.connect(
File "C:\Users\gabri\postgres-challenge-workspace\lib\site-packages\psycopg2_*init*_.py", line 127, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "grabel.ddns.net" (**.***.***.***) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states **connection refused by the host - (could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "grabel.ddns.net" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?)**

login to your server grabel.ddns.net and check if it is accepting connections on port 5432 and whether postgres is running on it.

Comment: Also, configure firewalls properly.